# nRF24L01+ Unable to set address

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-nano, communication, nrf24l01+, wireless

I'm trying to communicate between Arduino Nano and Arduino Uno using nRF24L01+.

I tried using RF24 by ManiacBug and TMRH20, but when I open the serial monitor after uploading the Example Programs Getting Started from ManiacBug and pingpair Program from TMRH20, it does not change its address.

The addresses for reading and writing I'm using are 0xF0F0F0F0E1LL and 0xF0F0F0F0D2LL, but the response I'm receiving is as follows:
[image]

I check all the connection and tried different examples available on the internet, but nothing worked at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set addresses using SPI commands.  For example a 5-byte transmitter address could be written as (MSB first):

```
  digitalWrite(CSN_pin, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(0x30); // write TX_ADDR register
  SPI.transfer(tx_addr[0]);
  SPI.transfer(tx_addr[1]);
  SPI.transfer(tx_addr[2]);
  SPI.transfer(tx_addr[3]);
  SPI.transfer(tx_addr[4]);
  digitalWrite(CSN_pin, HIGH);
```

where `tx_addr` is an array of 5 bytes.  Similarly you can write to the RX_ADDR registers, see the nRF24L01+ datasheet, section 9 for the register map.

Furthermore, the following code allows you to read the TX_ADDR register:

```
  digitalWrite(CSN_pin, LOW);
  SPI.transfer(0x10); // read TX_ADDR register
  data_out[0] = SPI.transfer(0x0);
  data_out[1] = SPI.transfer(0x0);
  data_out[2] = SPI.transfer(0x0);
  data_out[3] = SPI.transfer(0x0);
  data_out[4] = SPI.transfer(0x0);
  digitalWrite(CSN_pin, HIGH);

  Serial.print("TX_ADDR=");
  Serial.print(data_out[0]);
  Serial.print(data_out[1]);
  Serial.print(data_out[2]);
  Serial.print(data_out[3]);
  Serial.println(data_out[4]);
```

Comment: @MichaeIT I tried this solution, but no luck. I've gone through  https://github.com/nRF24/RF24/issues/211 thread, but still no luck.

Comment: Try writing and reading, as suggested in the above example.  If this does not work, then there is some problem with the SPI.

Comment: I tried this, and getting the response 00000. SPI of arduino is problem or nRF? As I tried different nRF and Arduino.

Comment: @MichaeIT I am successful in making it work on Arduino Uno by connecting MISO, MOSI and SCK pins directly to the ICSP header pins, but not successful in Arduino Nano.